# Inserting values to 2D array using pointers

Tags: c++, for-loop, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion

I successfully entered values to a 2D array without pointers

```
int main(){ 
    int A[2][3];
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            A[i][j] = 2*i+3*j;
            cout<<" "<<A[i][j]<<" ";

             }
    cout<<endl;
  }
}
```

And the output is

```
 0  3  6 
 2  5  8
```

Then I tried to reach the same outcome with pointers

```
int main(){

    int A[2][3];
    int (*p)[3] = A;

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
             *(*A+j)= 2*i+3*j;
             cout<<" "<<*(A[i]+j)<<" ";

        }
         cout<<endl;
     }
```

}

And the output is

```
0  3  6
32758  1  0
```

any idea why I got a different result for the second array?

Comment: But your second code sample doesn't use `p`, you are still using `A`. And of course `*(*A+j)` is obviously not the same as `A[i][j]`, there's no use of `i` in the first expression for instance.

Comment: BTW `[]` works perfectly well with pointers. So the correct pointer using code would be `p[i][j] = 2*i+3*j;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This left operand of the assignment expression

```
*(*A+j)= 2*i+3*j;
```

does not depend on the index i. In fact it is equivalent to `A[0][j]`

Thus elements `A[1][j]` stay uninitialized.

Instead write

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
         *( *( A + i) + j )= 2*i+3*j;
         cout<<" "<<*(A[i]+j)<<" ";

    }
     cout<<endl;
 }
```

Or with using the declared pointer `p` the program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int A[2][3];
    int (*p)[3] = A;

    for ( int i=0; i < 2; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j=0; j<3; j++ )
        {
             *( *( p + i ) + j ) = 2*i+3*j;
             std::cout << " " << *(A[i]+j) << " ";

        }
         std::cout << std::endl;
     }
}
```

That is the expression `*( p + i )` is the same as `p[i]` and the expression `*( *( p + i ) + j )` is the same as `p[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the pointer correctly. In fact, you are not even using it at all. `p` is a pointer to the first `int[3]` in `A`. You can use the subscript operator (`[]`) on it to dereference it, just like you do with `A`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int A[2][3];
    int(*p)[3] = A;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            p[i][j] = 2 * i + 3 * j;             // proper dereferencing
            
            std::cout << ' ' << A[i][j] << ' ';  // verify via `A`
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```